# NameError: global name 'FullLoader' is not defined

Tags: python, yaml

Environment:
python2.7
PyYAML 5.1.1

when I try to parse text.yaml with this command  :

```
rule_schema = yaml.load(open('/data/opt/rules/frequency.yaml'))
```

I get these error infos:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 109, in load
    Loader = FullLoader
NameError: global name 'FullLoader' is not defined
```

but it works fine in my test server(also `python2.7,PyYAML 5.1.1`) on the same command.

Have you ever encounter this problem and help to figure out the reason and solution?

Comment: Python 2.7 is end of life in 2020, and PyYAML has not been updated to the YAML 1.2 standard (released 2009). I suggest you update the former to 3.7 and/or the latter to ruamel.yaml

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have solved my problem by reinstall PyYAML.